# oracle sql dev, Using a subquery, List buildings where user has no interest

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently trying to get the database to list a buildings, BuildingNum, BuildingName and instname that have a user who has not Interest(interest.description = null).

```
(PK) = Primary Key
(FK) = Foreign Key
```

The database schema is as follows:

```
Building(buildingNum(PK), Description, instname, buildName, state, postcode)
User(UNum(PK), buildingNum(FK), Surname, FirstName, initials, title)
File(FileNum(PK), title)
UserAccount(FileNum(PK)(FK), UNum(PK)(FK))
Job(JobNum(PK), id, title)
Interest(JobNum(PK)(FK), UNum(PK)(FK), Description)
```

So far i have tried the following block of code:

```
select B.buildingNum, B.BuildName, B.instname
from Building B join User U
where B.deptNum = U.deptNum in (select I.Description
                    from interest I
                    where description = null);
```

I'm struggling with how to do this using a sub query, all i receive is an error as this doesn't work. Im not sure if i should be using the join like that or if i have added the subquery correctly. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want no interests, use `exists`:

```
select b.buildingNum, b.BuildName, b.instname
from Building b
where exists (select 1
              from users u left join
                   interest i
                   on i.unum = u.unum
              where b.deptNum = u.deptNum and
                    i.unum is null  -- no interests
             );
```

The subquery returns users (in a given building) that have no interests.  The `exists` is simply saying that at least one exists.

As a note:  `= null` is never used for comparisons.  It *never* returns a true value.  The correct syntax is `is null`.

Comment: Cheers. Thanks for the help!